# Mvc 4 EF Code First - questions on how to persistently store a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Background:** Final year project - creating web appliction using Mvc 4.

**Scenario:** In my application a user should be able to select a number of preferences and apply a preferential weighting to each preference. These preferences should then be stored in a list and used later on for other non-question related tasks.

Here's how a preference is defined, instances of preference become preference options, and how I think they should be stored:

PreferenceOption:

```
public enum Weighting { One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten }

public class PreferenceOption<T>
{
    public T PreferenceOptionSelected { get; set; }
    public Weighting Weighting { get; set; }
}
```

PreferenceOptions:

```
public class PreferenceOptions
{
    PreferenceOption<bool> WantsHouse = new PreferenceOption<bool>() { PreferenceOptionSelected = false, Weighting = Weighting.One };
    // ... could be up to 15/20 options

}
```

UserPreferences:

```
public class UserPreferences
{
    public List<PreferenceOptions> UserPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

So I want the model `UserPreferences` to persistently store all of a user's selected preferences. Say if there were ten preferences, would each preference be one row in the `UserPreferences` table, and a column `UserID` (say 1) would be 1 for each row for that user?

```
UserID | WantsHouse | OtherOption | OtherOption |
--------------------------------------------------
1      |  ???       | ???         | ???
```

Since `WantsHouse` has a bool and an emum value, how are both of these stored?

Is a list the best way to store these? It seems the right way to do it when using code first - but a list cannot be stored in a row - right?

Finally, do the other models (`PreferenceOption` and `PreferenceOptions`) described above need to persist? Would it be sufficient for them to exist only in-memory? They're purpose being only to facilitate a user selecting values, which are then stored in `UserPreferences`.

All help and feedback appreciated.

Comment: "but a list cannot be stored in a row" - you could if you stored the list as XML

Comment: I'd like to hear other suggestions/comments on what I've said above, before going down the XML route, as what I've outlined above is what I'm familiar with - I will look into XML though, maybe as a last resort.

Comment: I think the PreferenceOption should be an entity and you would have a relation ship between the user and his preferences. This way you will not limit the user preferences by the number of columns you have in the database and you will not have to use hacks like storing a list of values in a field and then parse/serialize them accordingly. It is up to the provider to define what store type is used for bool type. In Sql Servier this will be the bit type. For enums the column type will be the store type that corresponds to the enum underlying type.

Comment: @Pawel: Do you mean have a separate class/entity for every PreferenceOption e.g. PreferenceOptionOne, PreferenceOptionTwo...etc? And have an ID property that would map as a primary key in each PreferenceOption table? Performance-wise would this be an issue? Design-wise is it the best approach?

Comment: No, I think you should have just PreferenceOption entity that would represent all/any reference option. It would have a value to indicate what option it represents. Then in your database instead of having columns for each preference (which btw. is limiting you since you cannot have more than X preferences and you have to set nulls for preferences not chosen by the user) you would have a separate table with preference which would have Id, UserId and the Preference value. UserId is a foreign key indicating the user the preference applies to (1 to many relationship).

Comment: Just to confirm - the 3 classes above should remain as is? Have 1 db entity PreferenceOption that would represent all/any preference options - would I still not need class PreferenceOptions to do this, as PreferenceOption outlines the type that makes up PreferenceOptions? Then have another table, say SelectedOptions with ID, UserID, PreferenceOptionID? Would you care to go into more detail and provide an answer, so I get a better understanding and can select it as answer?